# Find the longest word in a sentence

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

This is my second attempt after I started to learn about STL. I am oblivious and need suggestions/advices on if there can be improvements made on this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string LongestWord(string sen) {

  vector<string> coll; //initialize vector

  istringstream iss(sen); //read the string "sen"

  copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), //copy from beginning of iss
    istream_iterator<string>(), //to the end of iss
    back_inserter(coll)); //and insert string to vector
  //istream_iterator by default separates word by whitespace

  string longestWord = coll.at(0);
  int longestCount = longestWord.length();

  for(auto element : coll)
  {
      if(element.length() > longestCount)
      {
          longestWord = element;
      }
  }
    return longestWord;

}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. When I run it, it always returns the last word rather than the longest word. I'm passing it a sentence like "This is a sentence with a long word" and it returns "word".

Comment: Actually, I ended with "word." which has 5 characters, which is why it shows the problem.

Comment: You never update the length of the longest word, `longestCount`, so the output is the last word that is longer than the first word.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: if you would like another review, please feel free to post a new question with the updated *working* code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user1118321 points out: just using your implementation, I believe you're missing a crucial line (inside your for loop and if-statement):

```
longestCount = element.length();
```

Which becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string LongestWord(string sen) {
    vector<string> coll; //initialize vector

    istringstream iss(sen); //read the string "sen"

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), //copy from beginning of iss
        istream_iterator<string>(), //to the end of iss
        back_inserter(coll)); //and insert string to vector
    //istream_iterator by default separates word by whitespace

    string longestWord = coll.at(0);
    int longestCount = longestWord.length();

    for(auto element : coll)
    {
        if(element.length() > longestCount)
        {
            longestWord = element;
            longestCount = element.length();
        }
    }

    return longestWord;
}
```

---

[Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6789498), it's better to use `std::` as needed. While it's insignificant here, if you work on larger projects it will cause headaches. Especially if you're learning STL, it's a good idea to learn what goes in the STL and the C++ Standard Library (ie within namespace `std`).

Instead of iterating over the string (when tokenizing into words) and again over the vector, you could just iterate once:

Below is a common way to find the maximum of a container of elements, in this case `std::vector<std::string>`, while taking advantage of `std::istringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string LongestWord(std::string str){
    std::string::size_type max_len = 0;
    std::string longest_word;
    std::string word;

    std::istringstream stream(str);

    while(stream >> word) {
        if(max_len < word.length()) {
            max_len = word.length();
            longest_word = word;
        }
    }

    return longest_word;
}
```

This function could be improved depending on how you wish to use it. You may wish to not count punctuation (recommended), you may wish to return a vector of strings if there are words of the same length, or you may wish to throw an error when given an empty string. These are all fairly easy to implement as needed.

Comment: I don't think I need longestCount = element.length(); because as you can see in the code, "longestCount" is dependent on the "longestWord". So whenever the "longestWord" changes, so does the "longestCount".

Comment: @austingae No because it doesn't update. You set that once before your loop and then it never changes.

Answer (score 3):

> after I started to learn about STL

You're on the right path, but you still have some way to go: you could have found the exact algorithm you needed in `<algorithm>`, and used it without any risk of error in a more expressive program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::string longest_word(const std::string& sentence) {
    using word_iterator = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;
    std::istringstream iss(sentence);
    return *std::max_element(word_iterator(iss), word_iterator(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
    });
}

int main() {  
    auto lw = longest_word("what is the longest word of this short sentence? really?");
    std::cout << lw;  
}
```

NB: `std::max_element` returns an iterator, hence the `*` in the return statement.

Note that this is also more efficient, since we don't have to copy words to keep track of the longest, but iterators, which are generally very cheap to copy.

You should avoid "raw loops" as much as you can!

Just a few more remarks:

- Take non built-in types arguments as constant references (`std::string` -> `const std::string&`) since it avoids a possibly expensive copy
- It's a matter of taste of course, but `this_style` has been consistently used in C++ over `ThisStyle` since the beginning.
- Comments aren't a STL memento (C++ programmers should know the STL or be able to find out about a particular class/function on their own), but should provide meaning (`// split the given sentence into words` for instance).

Comment: I don't understand this part: "[](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs"

Comment: @austingae : it's a lambda function. It sounds complicated, but it's just a locally defined function. The alternative is to define a `bool greater_by_size(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)` function somewhere else and pass it to `std::max_element`: `auto lw = std::max_element(first, last, greater_by_size)`